# How can I remove youtube-dl (NOT installed via snap or apt)?

Tags: youtube-dl

I installed `youtube-dl` from 
https://yt-dl.org
Since this is not installed from snap or apt-get, how do I get this removed?

Answer (score 7):

According to http://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html, there are four documented methods of installation.

Therefore, there are several possible methods of removal.

1. If you used `curl` or `wget` to download, then the file is probably at `/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl`

   Verify it, then remove it:

   ```
   $ ls -l /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan  5 10:07 /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl    // Yes, it's there

   $ sudo rm /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl               // sudo because it's not owned by me
   ```

   Alternately, if your output looks like this, then you likely used a different method, or you put the file someplace else:

   ```
   $ ls -l /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
   ls: cannot access '/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl': No such file or directory
   ```
2. If you used `pip` or `pip3` to install, then use the same tool to remove:

   ```
   $ sudo pip remove youtube-dl
   ```
3. If you used Homebrew to install, then use the same tool to remove:

   ```
   $ brew remove youtube-dl
   ```

Comment: thats it ! if found the file youtube-dl it was in usr/local/bin,